# Listing combinations from a given set of numbers with their totals

Tags: python, combinations

I use this code to generate combinations of three numbers from a given set of list.

```
import itertools

thelist = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
for L in range(3,4):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(thelist, L):
        print(subset)
```

Which works fine and the results look like this:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
```

I'd like to list the sum of produced combinations alongside. How can I do this?
So that the output would look something like this:

```
(0, 0, 0) =>0
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 0, 2) =>2
(0, 0, 2) =>2
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 0, 2) =>2
(0, 0, 2) =>2
(0, 0, 1) =>1
(0, 1, 1) =>2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just printing in a python `>= 3.6`, you can use f strings and simply do:

```
import itertools

thelist = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
for L in range(3,4):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(thelist, L):
        print(f"{subset} => {sum(subset)}")
```

For Python `<3.6` use: `print("{} => {}".format(subset, sum(subset))`